# C# object not destroyed when using COM/ATL interface in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, atl

Lately I was doing a little project that involved a DLL module (that was created with C#) and that I needed to use in my application (that was written in unmanaged C++) For this to work I was using ATL/COM.

I noticed that even though I'm using a [_com_ptr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in my C++ application for handling my core COM interface, C# object's destructor is called only when my application is closed.

Let me give you some source to make things a bit more clearer:

Some of my C# code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ITestCOM
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Connect([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] ushort value);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ITestCOMEvents))]
public partial class TestCOM : ITestCOM
{
   ...
   ~TestCOM()
   {
      MessageBox.Show("DESTRUCTOR");
   }
   ...
   public void Connect(ushort value)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I'm creating the .tlb file using something like this:
"**RegAsm.exe TestCOM.dll /tlb:Test.tlb /codebase**"

In my C++ header I have:

```
#import "C:\...\mscorlib.tlb"
#import "......\TestCOM.tlb" named_guids exclude("ISupportErrorInfo")

#include <afxdisp.h>
#include <atlcom.h>

class Unit : public ::IDispEventSimpleImpl<0, Unit, &__uuidof(TestCOM::ITestCOMEvents)>
{
public:
   BEGIN_SINK_MAP(Unit)
      SINK_ENTRY_INFO(0, __uuidof(TestCOM::ITestCOMEvents), 0x1, OnEventCallback, &OnEventCallbackDef)
   END_SINK_MAP()

   ...

private

   TestCOM::ITestCOMPtr mTestCOM;
   // NOTE: This would be the same as "_com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<TestCOM::ITestCOM,  &__uuidof(TestCOM::ITestCOM)> > mTestCOM;"
}
```

And my C++ source file I create my "mTestCOM" like this:

```
mTestCOM.CreateInstance(TestCOM::CLSID_TestCOM)
```

And basically that's it.. I can use any of my C# "TestCOM" object's functions like this:

```
mTestCOM->Connect(7);
```

The question is: 
Why my C# TestCOM object's destructor is called only when my application is closed, and not when my C++ "Unit" object is destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I'm not familiar with C# and COM integration, I do know that destructors in C# work *very* differently to destructors in C++. A C# object is memory-managed and garbage-collected. This means that at some point after the object stops being referenced by the application it belongs to and becomes 'unreachable', the garbage collector will destroy it.

So the first important thing is that the delay between an object being abandoned and the garbage collector destroying it is nondeterministic... it will happen "at some point in the future", which may well be at the point the application terminates.

Secondly, the garbage collector is not always running. There is the concept of "memory pressure", when your application is allocating large chunks of memory and the free memory available to it is running out... at that point, the garbage collector will fire to get rid of old, unreachable objects. If your application does not allocate lots of memory it will not suffer from any memory pressure and the garbage collector will not need to run.

If you want to deterministically clean up some of a managed object's resources, you will need to use something like the `IDisposable` interface and call the `Dispose` method explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely normal and a side-effect of the garbage collector.  Which only collects garbage, and runs the finalizer, when a managed app allocates enough memory to fill up a generation and trigger a collection.  If you don't allocate enough then this won't happen until the app terminates.

This should not be a problem, make sure that you don't use the finalizer to do anything other than release unmanaged resources that were not disposed.  Writing a finalizer is the wrong thing to do in 99.9% of all cases, finalizers are implementation details of .NET framework classes.  Like the SafeHandle classes.  There is otherwise no way to let deterministic destruction in the client app produce deterministic disposal in the managed code.  If you do need to dispose members then you'll need to expose a method that the client code can call.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, I've accepted Rook's answer, but both answers were equally good.